# How to pass data to another view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a view controller A with function as below:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
         [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        Events_TableViewCell *cell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        EventDetail_ViewController *eventDetailController = [[EventDetail_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventDetail_ViewController" bundle:nil];
        [[self navigationController] pushViewController:eventDetailController animated:YES];

        eventDetailController.title = cell.nameLabel.text;

        eventDetailController.Description.text = cell.lblDescription.text;
        eventDetailController.Date.text = cell.lblDate.text;
            eventDetailController.Location.text = cell.lblAddress.text;

}
```

I able to get eventDetailController.title value in View controller B(sample screen as below) but i failed to get description, date and location value. If i put NSLog in code as above, i will able to get the value.

[image]

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You probably wanna set up the labels and then call `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:eventDetailController animated:YES];` at the end of the function.

Comment: Hi Chunthan20, yup, tried but still the same.

Comment: Also, in EventDetail_ViewController, store the values in variable... and set the values to the label inside viewDidLoad.

Comment: Hi Chuthan20, can show some sample here? Thx

Comment: `@implementation EventDetail_ViewController
{
 NSString *_desc;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [Description setText:_desc];
}

@end`

Comment: Hi Chuthan20, thx for your feedback. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate information from one object to another unrelated object, one way is to use [notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification?language=occ). You'll generally want an object to ask to receive notifications like so:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  // view controller B
                                         selector:@selector(handleNotification: )
                                             name:@"Some Notification Name" // This should be something meaningful in your app
                                           object:soemObject // Either a particular object or nil if you want to receive the notification from any object
];
```

Then in your view controller A, you can send whatever information you want via:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Some Notification Name" // Same as above
                                                    object:self
                                                  userInfo:userInfo // An NSDictionary with whatever needs to be transmitted to the other controller in it
];
```

Then in your view controller B that you want to receive the information you write the method with the selector you sent to `-addObserver:::` above, like this:

```
- (void)handleNotification:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];
    // userInfo contains the data that was sent from view controller A
    // do something here with that information. 
}
```

This is a way to communicate between any 2 objects without directly [coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)) them together.